# Limited head turning with mouse in Unity 2d

Tags: c#, camera

I'm Using Unity 2d and I made it so that the camera turned with the mouse in the x axis no problem. But I want the camera to only turn a small amount. The mouse needs to have full freedom to move but the camera needs to stop at a certain point.

I tried making an empty game object and set it so if the camera position equals that gameobject position the camera would move slightly back but that resulted in a lot if camera clipping. Also tried altering speed but of course that doesn't work. Does anyone know how I can do this without camera clipping?
Sorry for the lack of code as my computer has no interest access. Currently my code basically is:

```
transform.position = newvector3.Movetowards(
        Input.GetAxisRaw("mouse X") * speed * Time.DeltaTime, 
        0f,  
        Input.GetAxisRaw("mouse Y")  * 0 * Time.DeltaTime
);
```

That might be a bit inaccurate but that's the basic of it

Comment: I don't have access to my code right now but I edited the post and put in what it basically is

Comment: Yes that code does not look right... are you multiplying by 0 by accident

Comment: No I only want it moving on x axis sorry I wasn't clear. I got to work now using Mathf.Clamp though

Comment: Post that as an answer so others can learn from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent clipping while using limited camera movement try something like this

transform.position = new vector 3(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, MIN_X,  MAX_X), 0, 0);

Of course replace MIN_X and MAX_X with the numbers of the minimum and maximum position you want the camera to be able to rotate to. This is off the top of my head so the code might not be 100 percent accurate. You can find Mathf.Clamp in the Unity docs if you're having trouble.